# Add table button in editor without Plugin

Tags: tinymce, editor, visual-editor

i want to add the "tablecontrol" ty the editor.
This is what I've tried:

```
function my_mce_buttons_1($buttons) {   

    $buttons[] = 'superscript';
    $buttons[] = 'subscript';
    $buttons[] = 'tablecontrols';

    return $buttons;
}
add_filter('mce_buttons_3', 'my_mce_buttons_3');
```

This does not work.
Any help is appreciated.

Lars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use this custom button for ad's in TinyMCE, i use `JavaScript` code to add/develop this one

look into this code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.wpse72394_plugin', {
          init: function (ed, url) {
            // Register command for when button is clicked
            ed.addCommand('wpse72394_insert_shortcode', function () {
                selected = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();

                if (selected) {
                    //If text is selected when button is clicked
                    //Wrap shortcode around it.
                    content = '[google-ad]' + selected + '[/google-ad]';
                } else {
                    content = '[google-ad]';
                }

                tinymce.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, content);
            });

            // Register buttons - trigger above command when clicked
            ed.addButton('wpse72394_button', {
                title: 'Insert google ad code',
                cmd: 'wpse72394_insert_shortcode',
                image: url + '/img/mobile_ads-32.png'
            });
        },
    });

    // Register our TinyMCE plugin
    // first parameter is the button ID1
    // second parameter must match the first parameter of the tinymce.create() function above
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('wpse72394_button', tinymce.plugins.wpse72394_plugin);
 });
```

php shortcode register for TinyMCE Editor in `function.php`:

```
function google_ads( $atts, $content = null  ) {

    ob_start();

    .....

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'google-ad', 'google_ads' );
```

You must read documentation about customs button add in editor:

https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons

and also read this article:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/guide-to-creating-your-own-wordpress-editor-buttons--wp-30182

Comment: Please do not answer with links only. Answers should be more than pointers to where someone finds an answer. Provide everything needed for an answer here on the page – with an [edit]. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @kaiser , next time i will provide **more data about the question** on the page.

Comment: You can still do that – with an [edit] to your answer (which will give you upvotes and therefore capabilities as well). Btw, your name sounds pretty much like mine :)

Comment: now i update the answer for the custom button with code like a little example @kaiser.